# Invoke pandas Series apply function with read_fwf

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

New to pandas here.
I have a pandas DataFrame called all_invoice with only one column called 'whole_line'.

Each row in all_invoice is a fixed width string. I need a new DataFrame from all_invoice using `read_fwf`. 
I have a working solution that looks like this:

```
invoice = pd.DataFrame()
for i,r in all_invoice['whole_line'].iteritems():
    temp_df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(r), colspecs=in_specs, 
                          names=in_cols, converters=in_convert)
    invoice = invoice.append(temp_df, ignore_index = True)
```

`in_specs`, `in_cols`, and `in_convert` have been defined earlier in my script.

So this solution works but is very slow. For 18K rows with 85 columns, it takes about 6 minutes for this part of the code to execute. I'm hoping for a more elegant solution that doesn't involve iterating over the  rows in the DataFrame or Series and that will use the apply function to call `read_fwf` to make this go faster. So I tried:

```
invoice = all_invoice['whole_line'].apply(pd.read_fwf, colspecs=in_specs,names=in_cols, converters=in_convert)
```

The tail end of my traceback looks like:

```
OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long:
```

Following that colon is the string that is passed to the `read_fwf` method. I suspect that this is happening because `read_fwf` needs a file path or buffer. In my working (but slow) code, I'm able to call StringIO() on the string to make it a buffer but I cannot do that with the apply function. Any help with getting the apply working or another way to make use of the `read_fwf` on the entire series/df at once to avoid iterating over the rows is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you save this column to a file and then use a single `read_fwf` call to read all rows at once?

Comment: I'll rather not write a file back to disk before read_fwf. Thanks for suggesting though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just doing:

```
invoice = pd.read_fwf(filename, colspecs=in_specs, 
                      names=in_cols, converters=in_convert)
```

Comment: I do not have a file as input. Instead the lines in the original file are saved in my input dataframe.

Comment: Do you have the file that all_invoice was constructed from?

Comment: Got the file but it has 3 different types of rows(lines); invoice, supplier, purchase_order. Earlier in my script, I use pd.read_table to read the entire file into a df and then subset  that df into 3 different dataframes based on the value at 20 to 22. 
all_df = pd.read_table('MARCHGRIEF.TXT', names=['whole_line'], header=None).  
all_invoice = all_df[all_df.whole_line.str[20:22] == "IN"]
similar for supplier and po. Unfortunately, read_fwf doesn't give me the ability to parse a line based on a condition. I need that because each type of line/row po, supplier has different structure.

Comment: Yes. It is a by product of a process that runs on the mainframe. No, the guys on that end won't write to 3 different files. They'll only give me one file.

Comment: So why not just use `read_fwf` on that and then filter given the column that contains "in" or whatever the other value is. That way the data is already segmented.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141916/discussion-between-okyere-and-grr).